# How to Consume a WCF Service without WebRequest?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I'm trying to interface with a web service. I am posting a SOAP Evelolpe and it returns a SOAP response.

I am able  to post to the service and get the response using Web Request and Response.But I want to do that using WCF. Can some body please help me to achieve this.

My HTTP Post :

```
public string HttpPost (string uri, string parameters)
{ 
   WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create (uri);
   webRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;  charset=utf-8";
   webRequest.Method = "POST";
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (parameters);
   Stream os = null;
   try
   { // send the Post
      webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
      os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
      os.Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         //Send it
   }

   try
   { // get the response
      WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
      if (webResponse == null) 
         { return null; }
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (webResponse.GetResponseStream());
      return sr.ReadToEnd ().Trim ();
   }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you need is:

- either a URL that you can get a WSDL from (often: `(url of your service)?wsdl`)
- or get the WSDL (and any supporting XSD) files from the service provider e.g. as a ZIP or a download

Next: from Visual Studio, create a project, and then right-click on `References` in your solution explorer and then pick `Add Service Reference` from the context menu.

[image: Add Service Reference Context Menu Item]

Either type in the URL (with the `?wsdl`) in the dialog box, or type in the disk path where your WSDL/XSD files are stored.

[image: Add Service Reference Dialog Box]

This will add a WCF service reference to that service to your project. You should now have an entry under `Service Reference` - underneath what you see, there lie a couple of hidden files, which contain all the generated code now necessary to call that service.

Basically, one of the file should be called `(name of your service)Client` - and it's in the namespace that you defined when adding the service reference (default is `ServiceReference1`). Using that namespace, you should be able to create that WCF client now:

```
using ServiceReference1;  // or whatever you called this namespace

public void CallService()
{
   YourServiceNameClient client = new YourServiceNameClient();

   client.YouShouldSeeServiceMethodsHere();
}
```

With this WCF client, you should be able to call service methods easily, and pass in parameters (strings etc.) to those methods, and possibly also getting back responses (as a string, or as a class) from that service method.

Comment: I wish I had the time to find the oldest question of which this is a duplicate. I'd add it to the tag wiki.